# Quoting in moderncv is not working; how can I force a quotation in moderncv?

Tags: xetex, moderncv, letters, quoting, csquotes

I am using [this `moderncv` template](https://es.sharelatex.com/templates/cv-or-resume/moderncv-banking). The issue is that when I try to put a quote in the letter template of `moderncv` with `\quote{}` it just do not work:

```
% recipient data
\recipient{Company Recruitment team}{Company, Inc.\\123 somestreet\\some city}
\date{January 01, 1984}
\opening{Dear Sir or Madam,}
\closing{Yours faithfully,}
\enclosure[Attached]{curriculum vit\ae{}}          % use an optional argument to use a string other than "Enclosure", or redefine \enclname
\quote{ A quote}


\makelettertitle

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis ullamcorper neque sit amet lectus facilisis sed luctus nisl iaculis. Vivamus at neque arcu, sed tempor quam. Curabitur pharetra tincidunt tincidunt. Morbi volutpat feugiat mauris, quis tempor neque vehicula volutpat. Duis tristique justo vel massa fermentum accumsan. Mauris ante elit, feugiat vestibulum tempor eget, eleifend ac ipsum. Donec scelerisque lobortis ipsum eu vestibulum. Pellentesque vel massa at felis accumsan rhoncus.

Suspendisse commodo, massa eu congue tincidunt, elit mauris pellentesque orci, cursus tempor odio nisl euismod augue. Aliquam adipiscing nibh ut odio sodales et pulvinar tortor laoreet. Mauris a accumsan ligula. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Suspendisse vulputate sem vehicula ipsum varius nec tempus dui dapibus. Phasellus et est urna, ut auctor erat. Sed tincidunt odio id odio aliquam mattis. Donec sapien nulla, feugiat eget adipiscing sit amet, lacinia ut dolor. Phasellus tincidunt, leo a fringilla consectetur, felis diam aliquam urna, vitae aliquet lectus orci nec velit. Vivamus dapibus varius blandit.

Duis sit amet magna ante, at sodales diam. Aenean consectetur porta risus et sagittis. Ut interdum, enim varius pellentesque tincidunt, magna libero sodales tortor, ut fermentum nunc metus a ante. Vivamus odio leo, tincidunt eu luctus ut, sollicitudin sit amet metus. Nunc sed orci lectus. Ut sodales magna sed velit volutpat sit amet pulvinar diam venenatis.

Albert Einstein discovered that $e=mc^2$ in 1905.

\[ e=\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n \]

\makeletterclosing

%\clearpage\end{CJK*}                              % if you are typesetting your resume in Chinese using CJK; the \clearpage is required for fancyhdr to work correctly with CJK, though it kills the page numbering by making \lastpage undefined
\end{document}


%% end of file `template.tex'.
```

This is the output:

[image]

I tried the following based in a question of this site:

```
\hbox to 0pt{\hss quote\hss}
```

However, it did not work. Any idea of how to "force" a quotation between the date and the title of the letter?

Answer (score 1):

I've copied this from the [ModernCV Sourcefile](http://ctan.cs.uu.nl/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/moderncvheadii.sty):

```
{{\null\hfill%
  \begin{minipage}{\quotewidth}%
    \centering%
    \quotestyle{"Hello this is my quote"}%
  \end{minipage}\hfill\null\\[2.5em]}}%
```

Place this behind the `\makeletterclosing` might solve your problem

Comment: Thanks for the help. However, with this approach the quoatation appears at the very top of the sheet. How can I put it between the title and the date?.